# How I do properly connect to an SQL server using Windows authentication?

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, qt

I'm writing a program in Qt that connects to a local database and writes to it using QSqlDatabase, but I've been unable to get a working connection between my program and the server.

```
qdb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

qdb.setConnectOptions();
QString serverName = "KIRKWOOD\TESTCLOUD";
QString ipName = "tcp:10.150.94.197,1433";
QString dbName = "Puma";

QString connectionString =  QString("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=%1;Database=%2;Trusted_Connection=Yes;").arg(ipName).arg(dbName);

qdb.setDatabaseName(connectionString);

bool connectionSuccessful = qdb.open();

if (connectionSuccessful) {
    writeLogWithNewLine("Connected to database.");
}

else {
    writeLog("Failed to connect to database.");
    writeLogWithNewLine(qdb.lastError().text());
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error in my log:

> "Failed to connect to database.
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired QODBC3: Unable to connect"

When I replace ipName with serverName I get this error:

> "Failed to connect to database.
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired QODBC3: Unable to connect"

When I change the driver to "SQL Server" I get this error:

> "Failed to connect to database.
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). QODBC3: Unable to connect"

I've done a lot of research and made a lot of changes to my code, from changing the Driver type to changing the formatting of "Trusted_Connection=Yes" to "Integrated Security=True" but I've had no luck getting anything much different from these errors.

This is frustrating because in this same program I was able to connect to a dummy database using SQL authentication perfectly fine, and on top of that, using this same machine I'm able to connect to the database through Visual Studio's Server Explorer. I've even directly copy pasted the connection string from visual studio but still got nothing. Is there something else I need to do here?

I would greatly appreciate feedback.

Comment: Try `"KIRKWOOD\\TESTCLOUD";`

Comment: Yep. *warning C4129: 'T': unrecognized character escape sequence* Never ignore warnings. May not be THE BUG, but definitely holding you back from finding it.

Comment: Have you considered that the DB may simply not be configured to allow you to access it? The "access denied" and "target machine actively refused it" bits of your error messages seem to point in that direction..

Comment: Oh my god. You are a lifesaver. I spent 2 days trying to figure this out and I feel so dumb. Thank you

Comment: Did you not get a warning for the improper escape sequence?

Comment: Compiler may have been trying to tell you the whole time. Crank up the warning level and never ignore them Compiler errors mean the compiler can't translate your code into a program. Compiler warnings mean the compiler could make a program, but it might not do what you're expecting. Warnings are the first line of defense against logic errors, so turn them on and turn them up **LOUD**.

Comment: Fix all warnings. @user4581301 is correct, if you spend a couple of days fixing all warnings you will find and fix no end of bugs.